# Creating a Many to Many relation in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models A and B (for example employee and projects) and need to be represented with many to many relation.

I have read the django docs. But, I'm little confused whether I should add B as many to many field in A or A as many to many field in B. I know both will work.

Advise as to which is more proper.

Comment: either ways it should be fine. Just figure out what makes more logical sense to you. - It looks like employee on projects makes more sense here, but i do not have a complete understanding of your requirement. Also, read this for more insights: http://charlesleifer.com/blog/describing-relationships-djangos-manytomany-through/

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself the following question:

> I'm more interested in choosing employees when creating a new project, or I'm more interested in choosing projects when creating a new employee?

This should help you decide which object should hold the relation.

For example: When you create a new `user` - you are more interested in choosing `groups`, rather than selecting `users` while creating a new `group`. So, in such situation, its more appropriate for the `user` to hold `groups` as `M2M` field.

Answer (score 0):

You may think of a project as a **subject** - project **is delivered** by employees, while thinking of an employee as an **object**  - an employee **might be working on one or many** projects. As an employee is who acts (and as such is more transactional), you might choose what's more appropriate.